# how do I paste into a layer mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This question was asked here [How do I paste into a layer's mask in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16903/how-do-i-paste-into-a-layers-mask-in-photoshop)

but none of the answers work for me! It seems to be a common question on the web, but something is going on with my situation, because absolutely zero of the suggested solutions work.

I'm trying to paste the contents of one layer A into the new layer mask of another layer B, using Photoshop CC on OS X.

I select all of A and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then I try any of the following:

- Click the "add mask" icon of layer B while the copied image is in the clipboard. I am told this will put it in the mask, but the mask is blank.
- Alternatively, add the mask to B first, then click on it, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This pastes the clipboard into an entirely new layer.
- Alternatively, add the mask to B, then click on it, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. This does the same thing as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
- Alternatively trying any of the Paste Special commands from the Edit menu. These all do the same thing as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

EDIT: It occurs to me that maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that layer A is RGB, while masks are grayscale.

EDIT 10/17/2016
This is solved. I am new to the Mac world, and when I read the instruction to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click, I was doing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click, when what I actually needed to do was <kbd>Opt</kbd>-Click.

Answer (score 2):

Two options.

1. Manually select the mask channel from the Channels panel. Doing this will allow you to edit the mask with the rest of your artwork still visible.
2. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the layer mask thumbnail in the layers panel. This will automatically select the mask channel and hide all other channels.

Any artwork pasted to a mask channel will automatically be converted to grayscale, so you can copy RGB layers with no problem.

Take this image for example:

[image]

After copying the image, I add a new gradient layer, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> that layers mask thumbnail in the layers panel and paste the image:

[image]

Adjust the mask using a levels adjustment:

[image]

Invert the mask then deselect the layer mask in the layers panel:

[image]

- [**Photoshop Help — Edit layer masks**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-layer-masks.html)

Comment: Oh, I figured out what the problem is. I'm new to Mac, come from Windows. When you (and other people) write to "Alt-Click" the mask, I was doing a Cmd-Click. What is actually needed is Option-Click. It works now. Sorry for the confusion.